# How can I test authenticated APIs created using Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have an API that requires authentication, created using Rails 5. The basic flow of the authentication is that the user performs a login with a username/password in a Base64-encoded `Authorization: Basic` header, along with an API key. This is then exchanged for an authorization token, which is recorded in the user database table and is good for some period of time. Subsequent API calls require this token in an `Authorization: Bearer` header.

The problem I'm having is that, when I try to test a controller that requires authentication, I'm having to go through this dance of logging the user in (to ensure that the `auth_token` is in the test database table, since this might be the first test that's being run, etc...) This is complicated, because, if, for example, I am testing a controller called `RecipesController`, and my authentication lives in `AuthController`, I need to switch controllers in order to perform the login stuff.

I've successfully done this in the past in `spec_helper.rb` using something like:

```
def login username, password
  current_controller = @controller
  ... setup login call ...

  post :login

  @controller = current_controller
  ... return auth token ...
end
```

However, as I've realized in [Why are parameters not being passed within my test in Rails 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292971/why-are-parameters-not-being-passed-within-my-test-in-rails-5), I believe this is messing up my test request, and parameters are being lost as a result.

This seems like a pretty straightforward pattern to use, though, so I'm wondering how to test it? I'd actually prefer to test the authentication separately, and just pass in a mocked user object, but I'm not sure how to do this, since I'm not as familiar with Rails as I'd like to be.

Comment: I would just extract the core functionality of creating a token out of your authentication controller so that you can simply call it your tests to create a token from a user records without having to make a HTTP call. Take a look at how you do [testing with Knock](https://github.com/nsarno/knock#authenticated-tests) if you want an example of this.

Comment: Also I would go with request specs instead of controller specs unless its a legacy app. Controller specs stub out actually sending HTTP requests and can let many bugs slip though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your Auth verifying function in ApplicationController(assuming your Recipes inheriting from this)

```
def current_user
  return nil unless auth_token
  User.find(decoded_token['user_id'])
end

def authenticate_with_token
  head(:unauthorized) unless user_signed_in?
end

private

def user_signed_in?
  current_user.present?
end

def auth_token
  return nil unless request.headers['Authorization'].present?
  request.headers['Authorization']&.split(' ')&.last
end

def decoded_token
  JsonWebToken.decode(auth_token) #use your own decoder class
end
```

You can then add `before_action :authenticate_with_token` on the actions you require authentication.

For tests you can add a helper to login the user so you don't repeat in all places you require auth.

```
module LoginSupport
  def login_user(user:, password:)
    valid_credentials =  { "email": user.email, password: password}
    post '/auth/sessions', params: valid_credentials

    valid_jwt_token = JSON.parse(response.body)["token"]
    { "Authorization": "Bearer #{valid_jwt_token}" }.merge(json_api_headers)
  end

  def json_api_headers
    {'Accept' => JSONAPI::MEDIA_TYPE, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => JSONAPI::MEDIA_TYPE}
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include LoginSupport
end
```

Then use the returned Auth token in your request in RecipesContoller tests or any other place.

Comment: This was a great answer. Along with the comment from @max to the question, this solved my issue (which I've been dealing with for some time). Thanks a ton!